# Getting character ASCII value as an Integer in Swift

Tags: swift, character-encoding, integer, character, ascii

I have been trying to get the character ascii code as an int so as then I can modify it and change the character by doing some math. However I am finding it difficult to do so as I get conversion errors between the different types of integers and can't seem to find an answer

```
     var n:Character = pass[I] //using the string protocol extension
     if n.isASCII
     {
        var tempo:Int = Int(n.asciiValue)
        temp += (tempo | key) //key and temp are of type int 
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, a `Character` may not necessarily be an ASCII one.  It would for example have no sense to return the ascii value of [""](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1FA82) which requires a large unicode encoding.   This is why [`asciiValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127002-asciivalue) property has an [optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) `UInt8` value, which is annotated `UInt8?`.

#### The simplest solution

Since you checked yourself that the character `isAscii`, you can safely go for an unconditional unwrapping with `!`:

```
var tempo:Int = Int(n.asciiValue!)     // <--- just change this line
```

#### A more elegant alternative

You could also take advantage of optional binding that uses the fact that the optional is nil when there is no ascii value (i.e. n was not an ASCII character):

```
if let tempo = n.asciiValue   // is true only if there is an ascii value
{
    temp += (Int(tempo) | key) 
}
```